# programmatically editing properties of item's uploaded in sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to **GET** the name,title,content type & document tag of **document** stored in **SharePoint document library** and **EDIT** it programmatically using visual studio 2012 with **Sandbox Solution**.

i have successfully get all of these properties in VS2012 and also updating successfully but when i click on update button it gives **Error: File Not Found**.

and after that  when i goes to my document page then all these properties looks like updated.
so, why it throw error every time i click on update button since all properties also updateing successfully.

my code is here:

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://<sitename>/");
      2: SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
      3: oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      3: SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"];
      4: SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items[0];
      5: oListItem.File.CheckOut();
      6: oListItem["Name"] = "xyz";  
      7: oListItem["Title"] = "abc";
      8: oListItem["Content_Type"] = "lmn";
      9: oListItem["Document_Tag"] = "pqr";
      7: oListItem.Update();
      8: oListItem.File.CheckIn("file name has been changed");
     11: oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates =false;
      9: oWeb.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before update the item you need to get it by this way.

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("siteUrl"))
{
   using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
   {
         oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         oWeb.Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

         SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"];
         SPFile file = oList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>() 
                        .Select(x => x.File)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        SPListItem item = file.GetListItem();
        if (item.File.Level == SPFileLevel.Checkout)
        {
            item.File.UndoCheckOut();
        }
        if (item.File.Level != SPFileLevel.Checkout)
        {
            item.File.CheckOut();
        }
        //Do update here
        //item["Content_Type"] = "lmn";

        item.SystemUpdate(false);
        item.File.CheckIn("SystemCheckedin");
        item.File.Publish("SystemPublished");

        oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        oWeb.Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```